# Create routing and controller definitions for separate administration in Kohana 3.2

Tags: controller, routes, kohana, kohana-3, administration

I am trying to build an administration section in a Kohana 3.2 environment where the goal is to target the following URL:

> domain/admin/controller/action/id

Currently I have a route that is defined and works fine as:

> domain/controller/action/id

My first approach to creating the admin version was this:

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin/(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))');
```

This will work, but my controllers inside the admin folder have to be another class name as the controllers outside of this folder. I thought if I would like to target `admin/user/index` I need a `Controller_User` in the admin folder. This only works if I type `admin_user/index`, because this uses the default route.

How do I set up admin folders with routing in Kohana?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you want it to be in the admin directory or not, but I assume you want to.

First, you have to specify the directory Kohana is going to look in for the route:

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin/(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(
        'directory' => 'admin'
    );
```

The you create a file called user.php in `application/classes/controller/admin/`

And the name of the controller is then `Controller_Admin_User`

I hope this helps.

Comment: but then i can only reach the controller over admin/admin_user correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you want to have admin controllers inside admin folder but you want the controller name without admin part - this is not possible, as class name must reflect the folder structure.